# select div(text) without span xpath

Tags: xpath

```
<div class="filters-list-item-content" xpath="4">
<span class="font-500">
Rodzaj konferencji:
</span>
Warsztaty
</div>
<div class="filters-list-item-content" xpath="5">
<span class="font-500"></span>
POH
</div>
```

I have 6 xpaths and try select all div(text) without text in span I try

```
//div[@class='filters-list-item-content']/*[not(.//span)]
//div[@class='filters-list-item-content']/SPAN[not(*)]
```

but it is select only text in span :(

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, this is what you are looking for:

```
//div[@class='filters-list-item-content']/text()
```

Output:

```
Warsztaty
POH
```

Comment: this don't work, because I have text in span and in div. I need get text only from div
''Warsztaty", "POH" without "Rodzaj konferencji:"

Comment: @VladimirRiabokon - It may be something to do with the library you are using; it does work as a matter of pure xpath: http://xpather.com/lwLYgb5l